# Easy way to OR 3 comparisons?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have an `if` block and I need to put a few comparisons in it for example:

```
if type(widget1) is tk.Entry or type(widget1) is tk.OptionMenu or type(widget1) is tk.Label:
    # do something
```

As you can see I am writing type(widget1) thrice. Instead, is there an easier way to do this?

```
if type(widget1) is tk.OptionMenu or tk.Entry or tk.Label:
    # do something
```

I know the above code wouldn't work here but just asking, is there an easier way to do it? I am making these kind of comparisons in multiple places, and so it would be helpful to write less. This isn't really a tkinter question, anyone can answer!! Thanks in advance!

Comment: `if type(i) in [int, str, float]:`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can use a list :

```
if type(widget1) in [tk.OptionMenu, tk.Entry, tk.Label]:
    #Do something
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `isinstance` which, in addition to its typical usage, accepts a tuple for its second argument:

```py
isinstance(widget1, (tk.OptionMenu, tk.Entry, tk.Label))
```

See the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance).